# Convert SQL query to TypeORM Query builder code

Tags: sql, sql-server, nestjs, typeorm

How can I convert sql query to TypeORM Query Builder?

```
SELECT * FROM GameType
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Draw.GameTypeID AS GameID, MIN(Draw.DrawDate) AS DrawDate
FROM Draw
WHERE Draw.DrawDate >= GETDATE()
GROUP BY Draw.GameTypeID) AS New ON New.GameID=GameType.GameTypeID
```